# How to express this ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following ARIMA model:

[image]

How can I express it in R?

So far I have

`arima(counts,order=c(2, 0, 0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0), period = 4)`

But I don't know how to express the Φ values (0.8, 0.7, 0.9) and the mean value (μ=1000) in the equation above.